# Risk and probability: Is there always infinite risk?

Tags: probability, risk-assessment

If there are an infinite number of events with a cost (risks), and total Risk is calculated by the sum of all individual risks multiplied by their probability, does everything have an infinite risk associated with it?

Comment: are you familiar with convergence of infinite series?

Comment: Nope! Not particularly experienced in this stuff. What is it?

Answer (score 2):

No. If the events $a_n$ all have a risk of $1$, and a probability of $2^{-n}$, then the total risk is:

$$\mathrm{risk} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{risk}(a_n)\Pr(a_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1\cdot 2^{-n} = 1$$

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand... Why is the probability 2−n ?

Comment: Simply by hypothesis. I considered a special arrangement of individual events $a_n$ and associated probabilities and risks to disprove your conjecture "does everything have an infinite risk associated with it?".

Comment: Oh sorry, I understand now. But unless in those specific circumstances, is that logic true? For example, if I choose to build a house: There are an infinite number of risks in construction, and from outside influences, meaning that the total cost of risk for me building that house is infinite?

Comment: That risk is not infinite either, because the high cost is multiplied by a very marginal probability. Perhaps it's more convincing to you that there are insurance companies: companies that (for a certain fee) are willing to take responsibility for high-cost, low-probability events for you. It doesn't speak in favour of your "infinite risk conjecture" that these companies tend to make a lot of profit, does it? Further examples of companies making profits with essentially the same strategy are casinos and lotteries.

Comment: But does the maths not show that the total risk/cost is infinite?